# calling procedure in Scheme using Dr. Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have this code in Scheme:

```
(define (calculate-mark MidTerm FinalExam Assignment Clicker)
(lambda(MidTermWeight) (/(* 3 MidTerm)10)
  (display MidTermWeight))
 )
```

Now when I calling this function by:

```
(calculate-mark 10 10 10 10)
```

It is showing this:

```
#<procedure>
```

Why it is not displaying any result?

Comment: As [mentioned in a comments on an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267741/calling-procedure-in-scheme-using-dr-racket#comment28533451_19267844), what is this code _supposed_ to do? At the moment, it defines a function called `calculate-mark` that takes four arguments (presumably marks for a midterm, final example, assignment scores, and clicker participation). It returns a _function_ that takes one argument (midterm weight), then computes the value of an arithmetic expression, but discards the values, and displays the value of the midterm weight. But what is this _supposed_ to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scheme, you can define a function like this

```
 (define (foo bar)
    ...)
```

or

```
  (define foo
     (lambda (bar)
         ...))
```

But you've done both so you're procedure returns another procedure: `(lambda (midtermWeight)...`. You'll have to call it again with the midtermweight to get a result.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I tried the way u mentioned, but still i am unable to get the result. I am a novice, It will be a great help if you could change my code so that i can call this like (calculate-mark 10 10 10 10)

Comment: @HariChaudhary Your code isn't quite clear, at the moment.  I think you'll need to describe more about what it's _supposed_ to do before anyone can propose corrections.